# spring-data-elasticsearch how to get field with dot in name?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

spring-data-elasticsearch version: 4.1
My index has documents with fieldnames like `"foo.bar": "123"`. How to declare them in entity?

For example like this(does not work):

```
    @Field(value = "foo.bar")
    private String fooBar;
```

I know this works for documents like:

```
"foo": { "bar": "123" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was added in Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.1 RC1 (2023.0.0)

See the [feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2502) and associated [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/2504).

Comment: thanks @Val for answering this, so I don't need to search ;-)